# It's possible to download an older version of Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, deprecated

I was trying to find a way to use or download a previous version of Spring Boot because I'm going to use Spring Security, as you know WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated right now

I'm sorry if there is an obvious answer to this, I'm new in Spring Boot, and I don't know if there's a way to do the thing I'm asking, and honestly I'm a little confuse about the new implementations.

Comment: Where would you download it in the first place? And have you then checked if they offer older versions as well?

Comment: Are you using maven? If so you just have to change the version in the `pom.xml` file. Any version < 3.0 should be fine for you I think like `2.7.7`

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the Spring project doesn't even offer downloads other than through Maven. So just, configure your Maven (or Gradle) build file to use your desired version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a build-system like Maven, you could easily replace the version in the pom.xml
Otherwise, you could look on websites like jar-download.com if spring-boot doesn't offer a download for the jar itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven you can change the Spring boot version `<version>2.7.3</version>` in the pom.xml file.
To use the Spring Security add the dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

First go to your pom.xml file and change your springboot version to any version below 2.7.0
then add the spring security dependency